# Searching/Detecting and Replacing tab in a java file in Intellij

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

Lets say I have a javafile in Intellij

```
public class Foo{
        public void bar()
}
```

As you can see before public there is a tab inserted. I'am trying to replace it with space/null but Iam not able to do so. I have tried regex in find/replace '\t','\t',"\t","\t" but it does not find it any of it and pressing Tab takes me to the next logical point instead of searching Tab. Can you help me how to replace tab in Intellij

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit-> Convert Indents and choose to Space to convert tabs to space indentation.

Comment: WHat you are mentioning seems to be indentation. I am not looking for indentation and reformatting. Iam looking for just one stray Tab that might have entered into code (and now code analysis wont allow that to pass in build).